# what does echo and pipe mean in a java command line environment?

Tags: java, echo, pipe

this is what im looking at :
`echo "A B C D E F G H I" | java Subset 3`

i don't really understand what `|` or `echo` signify here. After reading some stack overflow threads, i got the idea that since command line arguments don't go to System.in , echo helps to put it there ? ( i really have a very vague idea on this ) , and the `|` command supplies "each argument" "one by one" to the program ?

this was appealing , but when i tried testing them out in eclipse debugger , this is what i got :

[image]

i was expecting something special , but all the parts are just going to args[] as any normal arguments would. This is a bit confusing.

Comment: This is nothing to do with Java.  `echo` and `|` are constructs of whatever shell you're using.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. So it works on windows cmd just like it does in linux ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you pass the string

```
echo "A B C D E F G H I" | java Subset 3
```

as the command line arguments in Eclipse, you get the behavior you see.  If, however, you enter this on the command line, the *shell* handles the command first.  The shell interprets this as

1. Echo the string '"A B C D E F G H I"' to `stdout`
2. Launch a separate process to run the Java JVM, with arguments `Subset 3`
3. Pipe the stdout from the `echo` to the Java process' stdin

Then the JVM gets the arguments (`Subset 3`) and interprets the first string `Subset` as the classname to run and `3` as the arguments to the Java program.

Comment: this was a very helpful explanation. building on this , would i be correct if a say that now , as a result , ill be able use Scanner/BufferedReader on `"A B C D E F G H I"` in the same way as if the string was entered in the console ?

Comment: That is exactly correct.  The string is fed to the Java process on its stdin, which your Java program sees as `System.in`.